# How to not animate already present buttons during setLeft/RightBarButtonItems animated:

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

If you set left or right barbutton items using `setLeft/RightBarButtonItems animated:` and include an item that's already present, the present item will flash briefly.

I'm using the above method to add or remove a second button next to an existing button when changing pages in a `UIPageViewController`, and i do not wish the existing button to flash, only the button being added or removed to fade. Is there a way to achieve this without making a custom view?

When setting the items I'm of course reusing the first button, so the UINavigationBar should know it's already there and skip the animation for that particular button..

Comment: Why not just check to see if it's there already before trying to add it?

Comment: @patr1ck We are talking two buttons here. One is always there, the other one comes and goes. The problem is you can only set all buttons, not add or remove all of them, so the already present button gets "set" again.

Comment: @patr1ck Any solution to this issue?  I'm seeing the same issue with a navigation controller when pushing from a view controller that has one right button bar item to a second view controller that has two right button items.

Comment: having the same issue. Any luck?

Comment: Unfortunately no, still stuck at this.